# Package setuptools CLI into an executable

Tags: python, command-line-interface, setuptools, egg

I have a Python3 CLI (using Click) with the following setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    # ...
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        importdb=scripts.importdb:cli
    ''',
)
```

This works if I do `pip install -e .`: I can just run `importdb ...` from the command line. How can I package this into an executable file that can be run without `pip install -e`?

I have tried `python setup.py bdist_egg`, which produces an egg file, but trying to execute it gives `Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`. I'm not really sure where to go from here - I've searched for instructions on this but nothing seems to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+executable

Comment: @phd Thanks! I did see that question, but it doesn't quite answer mine. That question talks about running a given .py file as a standalone executable. I have a python package with entry points declared in setup.py, and I want those entry points to be exposed via the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip install`. Then copy to resulting `/path/to/venv/bin/importdb` script to wherever you want (maybe somewhere on your `PATH`, like `.local/bin/importdb`). As long as the *venv* stays at the same location on the file system, it should work fine, since the `importdb` script has the full path `/path/to/venv/bin/python` as its [*shebang*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). Otherwise look into things like [*pex*](https://pypi.org/project/pex/), [*shiv*](https://pypi.org/project/shiv/), [*zipapp*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html).